# Select non-duplicate records in a MySQL table column

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a large table with just 2 column. One is the primary id column and other is a data column.

I need to select only the records that is not-duplicated in the table. I tried the below query but it takes much time and not sure if it really work.

```
select * from (select column_name 
               from table_name 
               group by column_name 
               having count(*) = 1) x;
```

What do you think?

I am also open to other tries if it will do the job faster.

Comment: Is the second column `column_name` indexed in your table ?

Comment: Not sure why you need to select from that sub-query. Just using the sql from the sub-query would already be enough?

Comment: You mean select column_name from table_name group by column_name having count(*) = 1; ??

Comment: @AhmedMaher yes

Comment: Yes second column column_name is indexed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can left join the same table or use subquery to check for duplicates. 
This should be easier for SQL server as it would not count all duplicates.
Something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.column_name 
FROM
    table_name AS t1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            table_name AS t2
        WHERE
                t2.column_name = t1.column_name
            AND t2.id != t1.id
    )
```

OR

```
SELECT
    t1.column_name 
FROM
    table_name AS t1
    LEFT JOIN table_name t2 ON (
        t2.column_name = t1.column_name
        t2.id != t1.id
    )
WHERE
    t2.column.name IS NULL
```